# How to store NSArray on Secondary storage?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray

I am new in iOS, i want to store the values in NSArray onto secondary storage so that i can access it later, The array is large response from web service, i want to parse and show it, It is not efficeint to parse the array and store in sqlite DB, I want alternate way to save that array, may be in text file, so that i cant retrieve data from text file and parse it by my parsing function.
can we do that ?

please give me suggestions

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can save the array very simple to NSUserDefault

Comment: ok, but i think i cant, because array is having many elements, if i copied array in text file, the size of text file become almost 70 kb.

Comment: NSUserDefault have no limit (free space of device)

Comment: Ok thanks, will try to implement it.

Comment: If you wait 10 min.. I'm on the phone right now.. I will give you the code .. What I'm using

Answer (score 2):

to save the array to a text file you can use the method `– writeToFile:atomically:`, for more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToFile%3aatomically%3a) is the documentation of the function.

Answer (score 1):

For retrieving "yourArray" from NSUserDefaults.. you can write in your controller:

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

        yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        if (! [defaults objectForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sample"]])
        {
            //if nothing saved
            //... do whatever you want

            //Use this array if there is nothing saved
            NSLog(@"no saved array");
            NSArray *modelArray1 = @[@"New York", @"London", @"Paris"];
            yourArray=[modelArray1 mutableCopy];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"existing array");
            NSData *myDecodedObject = [defaults objectForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sample"]];
            yourArray =[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: myDecodedObject];
            NSLog(@"decode array init=%u", yourArray.count);
        }
            }
    return self;
}
```

for saving..

```
-(void)saving
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourArray];
    [userDefault setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sample"]];
    [userDefault synchronize];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best choice is `[NSArray writeToFile:atomically:]` if array contains simple objects.
To get array back use NSArray's `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` (Creates and returns an array containing the contents of the file specified by a given path.
+ (id)arrayWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath)

Comment: To clarify the "simple objects". The classes stored in the array should support the NSCoding protocol (Nowadays its NSSecureCoding). Lots of common classes support this (e.g. NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, etc.)