# Unable to retrieve NSMutableArray from NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I have an issue persisting data in local storage for an NSMutableArray containing a list of NSStrings.
I have a save method and a get method both appear to work when the app is running. However, once I close the app and restart the items in the array are gone.

```
NSMutableArray*ImageTags;
```

Get Data

```
-(NSMutableArray*)GetDataNSMutableArray:(NSString*)ItemName
{
    NSMutableArray *GetData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:ItemName];
    if (dataRepresentingSavedArray != nil)
    {
        NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
        if (oldSavedArray != nil)
            GetData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
        else
            GetData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return GetData;
}
```

Save Data

```
-(void)SaveDataNSMutableArray:(NSString*)ItemName:(NSMutableArray*)Data
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:Data] forKey:ItemName];

}
```

How items are added

```
[ImageTags addObject:Control.titleLabel.text]
```

How array is saved

```
[super SaveDataNSMutableArray:CVC_ImageURL:ImageTags];
```

How array is retrieved

```
ImageTags = [super GetDataNSMutableArray:CVC_ImageURL];
```

Comment: Cocoa coding conventions would prefer lowercase characters at the beginning of method names and variable names.  Uppercase characters start Class names.  `NSMutableArray *getData` and `-(void)saveDataNSMutableArray...` etc...

Comment: Check my other.. answer.. from here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14258828/1702413

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults always return immutable instances.

Unrelated:
(Conventions says that methodNames should always begin with a small letter).

Answer (score 1):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]
```

To dump all the contents from NSUserDefaults onto persistent store

Comment: I am not sure how this helps with my issue of storing an NSMutable array. Maybe I am missing something but in any case I tried it and same results.

Comment: -[NSUserDefaults synchronize] will only help you if your app is terminating. It's not a fix-all for user defaults problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your can not store mutable array to user defaults. Store the immutable copy and retrieve that and convert to mutable ones to access during the next launch.

Answer (score 0):

You can do synchronization while saving:

```
-(void)SaveDataNSMutableArray:(NSString*)ItemName:(NSMutableArray*)Data
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:Data] forKey:ItemName];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize] //add this code of a line.

}
```